# Использование Open XML SDK чтение данных с помощью SAX

Tags: c#, xml, excel, sax

Всем доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь реализовать чтение данных из Excel с помощью SAX, используя [данный пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg575571.aspx)
Проблема в том что данный код ничего не выводит:

```
static void ReadExcelFileSAX(string fileName)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

        OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);

        string text;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
            {
                text = reader.GetText();
                Console.Write(text + " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Код уходит в цикл но в условие не проваливается, уже не знаю в чём может быть проблема метод с DOM тоже не работает, везде в интернете всё у всех работает идеально и гладко а у меня как всегда =). Кто работал с этой библиотекой подскажите пожалуйста!
Вот [Файл](http://dropmefiles.com/4sjz6) который пытаюсь считать.

Comment: А файл исходный скинуть можете?